# Highcharts: how to add custom SVG icon on custom stock-tool button?

Tags: javascript, svg, highcharts

I have this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/delux123/c9tj1ywa/27/) with the code where I have defined a custom [stock-tool](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/stock/stock-tools) button like:

```
  lang: {
    stockTools: {
      gui: {
        customAnnotation: 'Custom action'
      }
    },
    navigation: {
      popup: {
        customAnnotation: 'Action config'
      }
    }
  },
  stockTools: {
    gui: {
      enabled: true,
      buttons: [ 'customAnnotation','customAnnotation','customAnnotation' ],
      definitions: {
        customAnnotation: {
          className: 'highcharts-custom-annotation',
          symbol: 'text.svg'
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

and where the `SVG` icon of the button is defined with the line `symbol: 'text.svg'`. The icon comes from pre-defined higcharts icons from [this link](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-dist/tree/master/gfx/stock-icons).
I wonder, how can I set `SVG` icon to point to my custom created `SVG` icon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `iconsURL` property:

```
navigation: {
  iconsURL: '...',
  ...
}
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/g9hct52j/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/navigation.iconsURL

**Docs:** https://www.highcharts.com/docs/stock/stock-tools